# Change color of Header for Distill blog Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

Anyone know how to change color of the header in Distill in Rmarkdown? I can change the color in the rendered HTML, but then everytime it re-renders, it overrides. Is there a way to change the header color with Rmarkdown when using the Distill framework?

Answer (score 2):

Cool, glad it worked! I also faced a similar issue. The entire default CSS that can be tweaked can be found in the Theming section here:

https://rstudio.github.io/distill/website.html

And then you can add this with:

```
output:
  distill::distill_article:
    css: styles.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer, added a .css file in the main index.Rmd, used the rendered html file and web browser to inspect the element to find the distill-site-nav element and changed the css that way. here is my .css file

```
  .distill-site-nav  {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFA500;
   }
```